Exercise 2.45 in Folland; associativity of product $\sigma$-algebra
I'm working an exercise in Folland's real analysis text, chapter 2 on product measures. I know of this question, but the answers seem to use tools to show the associativity of product $\sigma$-algebras not presented in the text (so far). I have another solution, though I'm not sure if it's correct nor suitable to the material presented so far; grateful for feedback.

45. If $(X_j,\mathcal M_j)$ are measurable spaces for $j=1,2,3$, then $\bigotimes_1^3\mathcal M_j=(\mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2)\otimes\mathcal M_3$. Moreover, if $\mu_j$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X_j,\mathcal M_j)$, then $\mu_1\times\mu_2\times\mu_3=(\mu_1\times\mu_2)\times\mu_3$.

Just to be clear: $\bigotimes_1^3\mathcal M_j=\mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2\otimes\mathcal M_3$.
Attempt:
As noted by the author in the text (page 65), we identify $X_1\times X_2\times X_3$ with $(X_1\times X_2)\times X_3$ and we write $\cong$. This means the sets are not strictly speaking equal, but there is a bijection between them, namely $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto ((x_1,x_2),x_3)$. In terms of measurable spaces, this map is an isomorphism (i.e. the function and its inverse are measurable). We now show this claim.
It suffices to check measurability on the generating set, according to Proposition 2.1. For example, we have
\begin{align*}
        \mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2&=\sigma(\underbrace{\{A_1\times A_2: A_i\in\mathcal{M}_i,i=1,2\}}_{=\mathcal{A}_1})\\
        \text{and }\mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2\otimes\mathcal M_3&=\sigma(\underbrace{\{A_1\times A_2\times A_3:A_i\in\mathcal{M}_i,i=1,2,3\}}_{=\mathcal{A}_2}).
        \end{align*}
Now, $\pi_{12}:X_1\times X_2\times X_3\to X_1\times X_2$ is measurable since $\pi_{12}^{-1}(A_1\times A_2) = A_1\times A_2\times X_3\in \mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2\otimes\mathcal M_3$ for every $A_1\times A_2\in \mathcal A_1$. And $\pi_3:X_1\times X_2\times X_3\to X_3$ is measurable by definition of $\mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2\otimes\mathcal M_3$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that the projections $\pi_i:X_1\times X_2\times X_3\to X_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ are measurable. So we conclude that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto ((x_1,x_2),x_3)$ is measurable since its components are the measurable projections $\pi_{12}$ and $\pi_{3}$ (recall Proposition 2.4). Its inverse is also measurable since the image of $A_1\times A_2\times A_3\in\mathcal{A}_2$ is $(A_1\times A_2)\times A_3$, a set in $(\mathcal M_1\otimes\mathcal M_2)\otimes\mathcal M_3$. Thus $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto ((x_1,x_2),x_3)$ is a measurable isomorphism. Hence the $\sigma$-algebras are equal in the sense that we identify $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $((x_1,x_2),x_3)$.
Since $$(\mu_1\times\mu_2)\times\mu_3((A_1\times A_2)\times A_3)=\mu_1\times\mu_2(A_1\times A_2)\mu_3(A_3)=\mu_1(A_1)\mu_2(A_2)\mu_3(A_3),$$the measure $\mu_1\times\mu_2\times\mu_3$ and $(\mu_1\times\mu_2)\times\mu_3$ agree on sets of the form $A_1\times A_2\times A_3\cong(A_1\times A_2)\times A_3$ and hence on the algebra on finite disjoint unions of such sets. By the uniqueness in Theorem 1.14 (the last assertion), they are equal.$\quad \square$
On the propositions and theorem mentioned above:

Proposition 2.1
Proposition 2.4 says that $f:X\to\prod_{\alpha\in A}Y_\alpha$ is measurable iff $f_\alpha=\pi_\alpha\circ f$ are measurable.
Theorem 1.14

